# отдать с сервера(Node js) mp3 трек и воспроизвести клиенту на web audio API

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, клиент-сервер, express, web-audio

здравствуйте. нужно чтобы на странице была просто кнопочка "плей" и по нажатию на нее начинал играть трек который присылает сервер на запрос. Вот так я пробовал:
код на клиенте

```js
// создаем аудио контекст
var context = new window.AudioContext(); //
// переменные для буфера, источника и получателя
var buffer, source, destination; 
// функция для подгрузки файла в буфер
var loadSoundFile = function(url) {
// делаем XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) на сервер
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'; // важно
xhr.onload = function(e) {
// декодируем бинарный ответ
context.decodeAudioData(this.response,
function(decodedArrayBuffer) {
// получаем декодированный буфер
buffer = decodedArrayBuffer;
}, function(e) {
console.log('Error decoding file', e);
});
};
xhr.send();
}

// функция начала воспроизведения
var play = function(){
// создаем источник
source = context.createBufferSource();
// подключаем буфер к источнику
source.buffer = buffer;
// дефолтный получатель звука
destination = context.destination;
// подключаем источник к получателю
source.connect(destination);
// воспроизводим
source.start(0);
}

// функция остановки воспроизведения
var stop = function(){
source.stop(0);
}

loadSoundFile('sound.mp3');
```

код на сервере

```js
// import the modules required in our program
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var path = require('path');

// initialize an express app
var app = express();

// declare public directory to be used as a store for static files
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// make the default route to serve our static file 
app.get('/',function(req,res){
 
 return res.redirect('/public/home.html');

});

var filepath = path.join(__dirname, '/music/sound.mp3');

app.get('/sound.mp3', function(req, res){
    res.set({'Content-Type': 'json'});
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
    readStream.pipe(res);
})

// start app on port 3000 and log the message to console
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("The player Server Has Started!");
});
```

в итоге после запуска сервера трек играет только когда в строку браузера забиваю адрес роута. Как сделать чтобы при запуске страницы  делался запрос на сервер, сервер "отдал " трек в буфер и чтоб клиент мог запустить его с кнопки "плей"?

Comment: Сам недавно написал приложение, в которое можно загружать мп3-файлы, оно их парсит, заносит мета-данные в базу данных, там тоже файлы парсятся в потоке. У меня вопрос: в моем случае это нужно было для считывания мета-инфы (исполнитель, название, альбом, год, длительность и т.д.); на кой хрен в вашем случае отправлять файл потоком, а не как обычную статику типа css, js, картинки? Или у вас файл будет генерироваться приложением?

Comment: ну как бы должен быть как мини плеер. маленький плейлист несколько кнопок

Answer (score 1):

Тогда проще кинуть файлы в директорию public/ с другой статикой, раз у вас Express и не писать костыли:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="public/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

В браузере есть несколько стадий загрузки документа. Вам нужна `DOMContentLoaded`, которая выполнится после загрузки html и построения DOM

```
function main() {
   // ваш код
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main, false);
```

Функция `main` как раз выполнится сразу после загрузки документа. Тут вы можете делать запросы на сервер и загружать другие ресурсы.

Подробнее описано в уроке на [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)